# Converting a googlefinance() market cap to another currency in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I can get the market capitalization of Bank of Montreal with `=googlefinance("TSE:BMO", "marketcap")`. The result is in US dollars. How do I get it in Canadian dollars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply the market cap with the USD-CAD exchange rate, like this:

```
=googlefinance("TSE:BMO", "marketcap") * googlefinance("USDCAD")
```